# Silent substitute command

Tags: vim

I've put this together to switch between tab styles:

```
let g:ToggleTabs__state=3-1
fun! ToggleTabs()
    let states=[ "8tab", "4tab", "4spc" ]
    let g:ToggleTabs__state=(g:ToggleTabs__state+1)%3
    let state = g:ToggleTabs__state
    if(state == 0)
        "echo "0"
        set tabstop=8 softtabstop=8 shiftwidth=8 noexpandtab
        %s/\    /\t/ge
    elseif(state == 1)
        "echo "1"
        set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 noexpandtab
        %s/\    /\t/ge
    elseif(state == 2)
        "echo "2"
        set softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab
        %s/\t/    /ge
    endif
    echo states[state]
endfun
nnoremap <silent> -t :call ToggleTabs()<CR>
```

It's giving me messages such as: X substitutions on Y lines.
How do I make it silent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nnoremap <silent> -t :silent call ToggleTabs()<CR>
```

Use `silent` command.